# how to make DateTime and "SetWallpaperAsync" work together?

Tags: c#, datetime, uwp

I am trying to do a UWP [app](https://github.com/moutasem1989/DynamicWall) that changes wallpaper and lockscreen based on the time of the day (as a start). I am facing difficulties implementing this:

I have the task "SetWallpaperAsync" on main page (I am making sure it works before shifting it to a background task) as fallowing:

```
private async Task<bool> SetWallpaperAsync()
{
   bool success = false;
   if (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported())
   {
      var imageID = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("HH");
      var uri = new Uri($"ms-appx:///Dynamic/Dynamic-{imageID}.jpg");
      var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
      success = await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(file);
      success = await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(file);
   }
   return success;
}
```

But it only worked once then it stopped, which lead me to believe that the imageID string is not returning the correct value (the value is between 00 and 23, corresponding to the hours in a day in a 24 format).
I have also tried to link a textblock to the same value and different formats, but it did not appear on the app homepage. I am not sure at all where its going wrong!

```
// Time format
var formatter = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("hour");
DateTime dateToFormat = DateTime.Now;
var mydate = formatter.Format(dateToFormat);
TimeDescriptionTextBlock.Text = mydate.ToString();

// another try with the time
TimeHours.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

How can I debug this code and see where its stopping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you output the `imageID` variable in the Output windows using `Debug.Writeline`:

```
var imageID = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("HH");
Debug.WriteLine(imageID);
```

You can see that the output is: `HH`.
The reason for this is that the format string `HH` works on `DateTime` variables, but you are actually calling it on the `Hour` variable only, which is just a number.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Remove the `.Hour` from the call: `var imageID = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");`
2. Just use the `Hour` as a number: `var imageID = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString()`;

Both solutions are equivalent and will yield a 24-hour format hour number.